# Filling HTML Table Footer with variable amount of datacells. DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am trying to accomplish the following.

I got an  html  table which varies in size. The size depends on the Result of an Sql Query so it is possible that it will be a 4 x 4 table or n x n Table always depending on the Sql Query.

Below is my code to populate the dataTable object. dataset is an Array which holds all the values and datatitle holds all the title.

All this works very nice and generates nice tables.

```
 $('#Example').dataTable({    
    "deferRender": true,
    "order":[[1,'asc']],
    scrollX: true,"data": dataset,
    "columns": datatitle,
}
  });
```

MY HTML Code as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-small downloadable" id="example">
<thead></thead>
<tfoot></tfoot> 
</table>
```

What i want to do now is to populate the Footerrow with the Sum Values of the respective column. The Code below would work if I added as many

```
<td></td>
```

to the footer row as followed. In this example it would give me the summary of the first 2 columns.

```
<tfoot> <td></td> <td></td> </tfoot>




   var table = $('#'+example).DataTable();

    table.columns( ).every(function(){;
  $( this.footer()).html( this.data().reduce( 
    function (a,b) { 
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    return a+b;     } )); 
    });
    $(table.column(0).footer()).html("Gesamt");


  }
```

What I want is to make this variable with out having to enter a certain amount of `"<td></td>"` Cells in my HTML footer Element.

Thank you for you help. I hope there is a solution besides hacking it with JS into the HTML Document.